# How to add transition to a changing image (with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, sass, transition, translate-animation

I made a function in which an image’s `src` changes as I scroll the page.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {

    var textPartitionsCercleDiv = document.getElementById("text-partitions-cercle")
    var textPartitionsDistanceFromTop = textPartitionsCercleDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top
    var texteMichelle = document.getElementById("michelle-text")
    var texteMichelleTop = texteMichelle.getBoundingClientRect().top * 0.2

    if (texteMichelleTop > 200) {
        document.getElementById("img-partitions").src = "partition-cercle2.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("img-partitions").src = "partition-cercle1.png";
    }
})
```

Where in the CSS should I add the `transition` property so it changes smoothly from one image to another? Everything I’ve tried didn’t work properly.

Comment: You can't animate or transition an image src. Though you could make it fadeout, change the src and then fade back in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have structured it differently.

Insert the two images and give them each different class.
Using Jquery/javascript to trigger the new class which makes the transition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#eb_onclick").click(function() {
  $("#mycontainer img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
});
});
```

```css
#mycontainer {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#mycontainer img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#mycontainer img.transparent {
opacity:0;
}
#eb_onclick {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="eb_onclick" >Click me to toggle</button>
<div id="mycontainer" class="shadow">

  <img class="bottom" height="100px" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/26/07/45/valais-3562988_960_720.jpg" />
  <img class="top"  height="100px"  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/26/17/16/daisies-5343423_960_720.jpg" />
</div>
```